# Post dynamic content with ajax setInterval

Tags: javascript

I have a multiple tables as below, i want to print the name every 2 seconds on my first table without interrupting table2, if i use innerHTML it's always printing on top (above table1 & table2, but i need the variable on a specific location like in my case table1, if i use document.write on change() function it's keep looping the function infinitely and not coming out means table1 & table2 not showing up? could you please suggest the better way to resolve this?

I have the following code on my update.php

```
<html>  
<head>  
<link href="css/sample.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 

<div id="changeText" ></div>  

<script type="text/javascript">    
var text = ["Welcome", "David", "Paul", "John"];  
var counter = 0;  
var elem = document.getElementById("changeText");   


function change() {  
elem.innerHTML = text[counter];  
counter++;  
if(counter >= text.length) { counter = 0;   
}


</script> 

<body>  
<tr>  
<td> 
<table align="left" width=15%>  
<td <B><font color="green">Name:<script type="text/javascript">setInterval(change, 2000);
</script>  
</font><br>  
</td>  
</table>  
<table id="sample" width=70% cellpadding="2" cellspacing="1" border="1">
<th class="sno" colspan="2">SNO</th>
<th class="fname" colspan="2">FIRST NAME</th>
<th class="lname" colspan="2">LAST NAME</th> 
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</body>
</html>
```

My goal is print the array of text under this tag

```
<td <B><font color="green">Name:<script type="text/javascript">setInterval(change, 2000);</script></font>
```

it should keep printing every 2 seconds with a name change...

Comment: you have syntax error in 'change' function

Comment: what is the syntax error? i don't see any error ,it's printing the text on top of my web page, where i need its under a table.

Answer (score 0):

You had some syntax errors :

http://jsfiddle.net/gFWeF/6/

```
<html>

    <head>
        <link href="css/sample.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table align="left" width=15%>
                    <td><font color="green">Name:</font>
                    <span id="myname"></span>
                    </td>
                </table>
                <table id="sample" width=70% cellpadding="2" cellspacing="1" border="1">
                    <th class="sno" colspan="2">SNO</th>
                    <th class="fname" colspan="2">FIRST NAME</th>
                    <th class="lname" colspan="2">LAST NAME</th>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </body>

</html>
<script>
    var text = ["Welcome", "David", "Paul", "John"];
    var counter = 0;
    var elem = document.getElementById("myname");


    function change() {
        elem.innerHTML = text[counter];
        counter++;
        if (counter >= text.length) counter = 0;
    }

    change();
    setInterval(function() {
        change()
    }, 2000);
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for you reply, if you got my question properly, i need the change() function return value under the <td> tag, it should print right after the Name: left corner but here the change() function reture value is always printing on top.